# Crystal Reports 2011: Bobj is undefined

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm having issues with this error and as a result Crystal Reports will not display. I've looked through Google results and posts here on SO, but have been unable to fix the issue. As a heads-up: my default website is on my D drive, rather than C.

Here are the things I've tried:

- Create a virtual directory pointing to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client in the default website.
- Copy aspnet_client to the project folder and to d:\inetpub\wwwroot.
- Put the crystalreportviewers13 directory directly under the project
  folder, and "add key="ResourceUri"
  value="/crystalreportviewers13"/" to the web.config.
- Performed the steps listed here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/ef56f72b-7ede-47d8-ba9e-9e63b9ac0203

None of that had any effect.

Any suggestions for what else I can try?

Comment: do you get the error when you run the report from within CR?

Comment: No. This is an issue with running through ASP.NET. It's very well-documented as an issue, and there are several fixes listed online (you can see the related posts list to the side,) but none of the fixes listed that I have found work.